# Sending only one string as parameter to JsonObjectRequest (NOT key-value)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I need to pass a String as a parameter in the following format: ["default"]
[image]

How should I build my JSONObject in order to do:

```
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        ...
 }
```

I've tried:

```
    String modeParam = "[\"" + mode.toLowerCase() + "\"]";
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("", modeParam);
```

Is there another way to send just a String? 'Cause it would be great if I could avoid using a map since it's not what I need for this type of body.

Update, Ive tried this as well:

```
    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
    jarray.put(mode.toLowerCase());
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("", jarray);
```

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus But then how can I achieve this? I mean how do I get to pass ["default"] as a parameter?

Comment: JSON supports arrays or key-value objects. Nothing else.

Comment: Try to create a JSONArray and put "default" inside it

Comment: This is (basically) the same the same question that you just asked and deleted! Because another user @Abnerescócio took time and effort to answer question--I consider it rude to delete the question without warning. I believe that editing your original question would have been more considerate.

Comment: @Barns I'm aware and I regret it. I thought my question was poorly formulated but I should have just edited it. I'm sorry.

Comment: No issue!  Just consider that people taking the time to answer a question get frustrated when suddenly the question no longer exists...time and effort wasted. No worries... I wish you success getting an answer to your question!

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus I've updated my question but it's still not working, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the body text to JSONArray:

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
jarray.put("default");
```

And you will have an array with size = 1.

Comment: Thanks I ended up solving it but changed it to Jsonarrayrequest

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:
(basically ended up doing  ajsonarrayrequest instead)

```
   JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
    jarray.put(mode.toLowerCase());
    final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, jarray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() { 
    ....
```